How to make std::format-like function fast for custom output types
I have a string-like type and would like to implement a std::format-like function to create instances of my string-like type.  A minimal working example of what I am doing is a string type with a custom allocator:
struct myalloc : std::allocator<char> {};
using mystring = std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, myalloc>;

Since std::format_to takes an iterator, my first thought was to format to an iterator, as in:
template<class ...Args> constexpr mystring
myformat(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args &&...args)
{
  mystring ret;
  std::format_to(std::back_inserter(ret), fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return ret;
}

Unfortunately, the performance of this function is abysmal.  For example, formatting a 256-byte string x256 with std::format("{}", x256) takes around 60ns on my machine, while myformat requires 790ns, which is 13 times slower!  Those exact numbers are with gcc on an AMD EPYC CPU, but I see similar results with gcc 14.1/libstdc++ and with clang++ 18.1/libc++.
My question: how can I leverage the formatting library to create custom output types without paying such a huge performance penalty?
update: Miles Budnek suggested using std::formatted_size.  This version of the code does improve things:
template<class ...Args> constexpr mystring
myformat(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args &&...args)
{
  mystring ret(std::formatted_size(fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...), '\0');
  std::format_to(ret.data(), fmt, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return ret;
}

However, this still takes 134ns, so more than twice as slow as std::format.  Moreover, it would be nice to generalize the approach to vformat, and unfortunately there's no "v" equivalent of formatted_size.  Without some sort of tuple_size, I don't know how to do the equivalent of std::apply on a format_args.
update2: I guess I can implement a vformat equivalent by introducing a dummy iterator that just counts characters to see the size of the buffer.  Strangely, this myvformat function is actually faster than the function that called std::formatted_size, so I reimplemented myformat like this:
struct counter {
  std::size_t n{};
  using difference_type = long;
  auto operator*() const { return std::ignore; }
  counter &operator++() { ++n; return *this; }
  counter operator++(int) { return counter{n++}; }
};
static_assert(std::output_iterator<counter, char>);

constexpr mystring
myvformat(std::string_view fmt, std::format_args args)
{
  counter c;
  c = std::vformat_to(c, fmt, args);
  mystring ret(c.n, '\0');
  std::vformat_to(ret.data(), fmt, args);
  return ret;
}

template<class ...Args> constexpr mystring
myformat(std::format_string<Args...> fmt, Args &&...args)
{
  return myvformat(fmt.get(),
           std::make_format_args(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

That brings myformat down to 85ns, compared to 60ns for std::vformat to a std::string, which is better but still a significant penalty.  By contrast, it costs 72ns to call std::format and then copy the result into a mystring.  Unfortunately, in my real application I can't do this, because for security reasons the contents is not supposed to live in the normal heap.

I suspect std::back_inserter is the issue.  I would try getting the size with std::formatted_size, create an appropriately-sized string, and then std::format_to the string without needing a std::back_inserter.

Back inserter is not the most efficient way to put items into a string. Each character insertion requires a bounds check.

Most likely the problem is that the standard library implementation doesn't optimize for appending to a contiguous container. I recommend reporting to your vendor and in the meantime you could use {fmt} where this optimization has been added even for strings with custom allocators.
As another workaround you could precompute the size with std::formatted_size as suggested by Miles Budnek. It is likely not as efficient as having contiguous iterator support but you won't need to add dependency on {fmt}.

Well, it's two different standard libraries from two different vendors (gcc libstdc++, and llvm libc++).  Since both exhibit the problem, I'm unlikely to get it fixed.  What's frustrating is that std::string is faster, so I know it's possible to be fast, just maybe not with public interfaces?

I would say it's likely to get fixed, it will just take time. Public interfaces got you most way there but I don't think you'll be able to completely close the gap just with them.
